# How to Start a Samba smb Server from an Android App?

Tags: android, samba, smb

Problem : Implementation of setting up a Samba Server from an Android Phone (Similar to **LAN Drive App** on Playstore [Link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fr.webrox.landrive&hl=en_IN) )

I've searched the internet and couldn't find server side tutorials (client side smb communication tutorials were plenty).

Can anyone give me an headstart on how to start implementing smb server on Android App ?

Comment: Related [Using SMB server without root access](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/1705/3573)

Comment: @MorrisonChang : They are all mentioning installing samba server app. I'm asking about how to implement in the app I'm developing.

Comment: 1) Asking for off-site resources is off-topic. 2) In what context are you using a samba server? Do you have root on the device? (read link for why its needed in most cases). Have you not found a SMB server in Java?

Comment: @MorrisonChang: 1) Don't really know if it's offsite or not. 2) I want to develop a custom app to share a particular folder via smb protocol for a secondary device to access the files. Mostly the devices will be handled by users and it won't be rooted (secondary device is non-windows so rooted won't be necessary I guess). 3) I'm still searching for SMB server setup using Android SDK and any Java libraries.

Comment: How will secondary devices know to connect to server (SMB isn't magic)? You should specify what is the secondary device (Android, custom hardware?, iOS?) Over WiFi, over mobile network? I feel this is a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/159081) without more context as to why sharing files.